# Preventing screen recording apps

Tags: desktop-application, screen-recording

If I have a website that contains **paid** videos and I want to prevent authorized / unauthorized users from downloading the video, we can make it ***as difficult as we can*** but we still cannot 100% prevent stealing videos.

A user still can record screen using many existing apps, I thought about it too much and looked for anything I can do to prevent it but as I got OS will not allow web browsers to detect screen record apps.

**Q1. But can I develop a program (desktop app) that can detect screen recorder apps?**

I'm asking because if I could manage to build such a program I can use it to know whether the user records the videos or not **while** opening the website and hence take a counteraction.

**The flow would be like so:**

- Whenever a user opens my website, I check if the desktop app is running or not.
- If it is not, the video will not be played until the app is run.
- If the desktop app is running, then check if there is a screen recording app is also running at the same time or not.
- If a screen recording app is running, then the video won't be played.

**Q2. Is this idea even possible to implement?**

Comment: Even if you could detect the recording of the screen by a local application process, there are several screen capture devices available that attach inline with the monitor cable which you'll never be able to prevent...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot determine what another program is doing, so you cannot detect that a program is recording the screen.

You can, however, determine what programs are currently running. So at best you can tell that “`RecordLive!.exe`” is running, or “`VidCapture.exe`” is running, and refuse to play your video if either are running, or stop it if such a program starts.

Unfortunately, if a new capture program comes out you’ll have to update your list. Or if I write my own “`MyCapture.exe`” you’ll never detect it. Or worse, if I *rename* an *existing* program to “`MyCapture.exe`”, you won’t detect it.

So, in short: nice theory, but not practical.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're right. I was just trying to see if that was possible. It's really disappointing that we're in 2018 and you cannot protect your own data.

Comment: I hope downvoters at least tell what is wrong with the question so that it can be improved.

Comment: @HossamAhmed I don't know what the system tells you, I thought it did, but your question is being voted to close for being too broad and based on opinion, not fact. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Yes.. you can write a program which ends (kills) all the programs except chrome.exe and explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If website security is of utmost importance, one possible way to block screen recorders is to package your website inside a desktop app which takes care of security. One such tool that does that is [Website Kiosker](https://websitekiosker.com/).

For external camcorders, the tool can show user specific watermark (like username or email) on random locations on screen so the real pirate can be identified!

Disclaimer: I am associated with Bitss Techniques. The only intention here is to provide a genuine option to the question asked.